# Objective-C NSMutableArray only returning one item

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to print out a list of objects in my `NSMutableArray` via `NSLog`, but for some reason, it is appearing to be null. Basically, I have a to-do list that when the user enters a new string to add to the tableview, it will also add that item to the NSArray so I can save it to the device.

**AddToDoItemViewController.m**

```
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"
#import "ToDoItem.h"

@interface AddToDoItemViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@end

@implementation AddToDoItemViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.toDoItem.itemList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a     little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender     {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue     destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;

    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;

        NSLog(@"Trying to add to array: %@", self.toDoItem.itemName);
        [self.toDoItem.itemList addObject:self.toDoItem.itemName];
        NSLog(@"Array contents: %@", self.toDoItem.itemList);
    }
}

@end
```

**AddToDoItemViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ToDoItem.h"

@interface AddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController

@property ToDoItem *toDoItem;

@end
```

**ToDoItem.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ToDoItem : NSObject

@property NSString *itemName;
@property BOOL completed;
@property (readonly) NSDate *creationDate;
@property NSMutableArray *itemList;

@end
```

Now from my AddToDoItem.m file, when I use `NSLog` to try to output the Array I get this:

```
2016-02-24 01:04:49.668 ToDoList[4025:249117] Trying to add to array: ok
2016-02-24 01:04:49.669 ToDoList[4025:249117] Array contents: (null)
```

**** The 'ok' was the text I entered *****

Comment: can you show your ToDoItem.m

Answer (score 3):

You did not initialise the array before adding to it, add `self.toDoItem.itemList = [NSMutableArray new];`

Edit:

oh i see you added `self.toDoItem.itemList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in the viewDidLoad, but this is not the right place to put it, it should be after `self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];` or inside the init method of `ToDoItem`

Comment: fonix I have one doubt , if he initilize in under with prepare for segue how will u get the array value , the last value only get na bro

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried adding it right after `self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];`, but what that ends up doing is re-initializing the array and therefore clearing all the items in it.

I figured if I initalized it in the onDidLoad, it would persist

Comment: well, you are going to have to change something quite significant to your logic then, since you are reassigning `self.toDoItem`, so at that point you have lost any previous ones anyway. maybe you should take that out? then you will have your previously inited array from the viewDidLoad

Comment: Shouldn't it be adding the item to the `NSMutableArray` that is directly in the class object though?

Comment: it should, but the fact that you have `self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];` right before it will make your array get reset to null, because you are assigning a completely new object to `self.toDoItem`.

Comment: Ohhh...I see! Would it be better then to instead of storing the items in an array, just store them to the device once they're created?

Comment: im not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but i would think getting rid of that `self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];` might be all you need to do

Answer (score 0):

First, you need create an init method at ToDoItem.m

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Any custom setup work goes here
        self.itemList =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

then run your project again.

Comment: For some reason doing this still returns a null array

Comment: Give me one case return null.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising the Array( itemList ) before ToDoItem is initialised, so initialised array remains nil. So, it cannot store any object.

Modify code as below,

```
self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
self.toDoItem.itemList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

you can add above lines of code either at viewDidLoad or at Segue Method

hope it helps you.

Comment: Please Uncomment  self.toDoItem.itemList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; this line of code in viewDidLoad.